# Help identifying cactus/succulent and trimming

Tags: identification, succulents, cactus

I decided to try making a terrarium with a bowl I had in the house. The plants I bought to put in it weren't labelled with what they were and in the few months since building it, one has grown like crazy and is getting squashed up against the side.

My question is, can anybody identify what it is? And can I trim it to fit in the bowl, or should I remove it and replant it on it's own?

Thanks!

[image: cactus]

Comment: Nice terrarium, James!  You'll probably need to transplant it in another vessel.  How about a tall cylindrical vase to sit as grouping next to this one?  You'll easily be able to propagate this guy...keep a theme going.  I love cactus but having all different kinds of pots looks...chaotic?

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm going to look at getting a bigger pot to put this one in on it's own and then I'll find a new (more suitable!) cactus to take it's place in the terrarium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its Austrocylindropuntia subulata, and it will need potting up separately - this plant gets 3-4 metres high and is used as fencing in warm countries, although its unlikely to reach that size contained in a pot of its own - but it's not really suitable for growing with other, smaller specimens of cactus. More info here http://www.llifle.com/Encyclopedia/CACTI/Family/Cactaceae/4096/Opuntia_subulata

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't expect that. I'll definitely have to move it to another pot.

Answer (score 1):

The succulent in the front seems to be *Huernia Keniensis*

I'm not an expert, but I think it is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The one in front is definitely a C. Subulata, and it will indeed get very large. They are frost tender, so don't expose them to sub-40s temperatures (F) for too long.

Also, don't be concerned if/when the flabby little "leaves" fall off.